# D720202 mPCIe to USB3.0

Tags: usb, 18.04, pcie

Trying to get this mPCIe USB3.0 card to be recognized... Ubuntu 18.04

When i boot there is one more PCI bridge added to lspci but nothing more ....

There was an old kernel driver addition mini cd that came with it -- im sure its usless, kernel listed was 2.6.32 ... for xhci

Im reluctant to try this old thread solution ...

[USB 3.0 express card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/812372/usb-3-0-express-card)

`pciehp.pciehp_force=1` , i dont think pciehp is used anymore

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that xchi is working --- on older systems with a BIOS that does not support USB3.0.....

You MUST disable legacy usb support in BIOS ...

Still not 5Gbit transfer, but it is faster than USB2.0.

Slight drawback is that you lose being able to boot from a USB flash drive or similar.